# How fill references in entity with NHibernate? No more INHibernateQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

In our application we are using NH2 with NHibernate.Linq. We want to upgrade to the latest version!

So I've read that since NH3 the Linq functionality is 'incorperated' into the NH assembly.

Now; I've got NH4 'installed' but our code base must be upgraded too.

In our NH2 implementation we used:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> of entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> of entities.</returns>
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable() {
        return this.Session.Linq<T>();
    }
```

In NH4 this is/will/must be:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> of entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> of entities.</returns>
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable() {
        return this.Session.Query<T>();
    }
```

We have an extension method to add eager loading:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds eager-loading for <paramref name="alias"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Queryable type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">A queryable.</param>
    /// <param name="alias">An expression that tells what to eager load.</param>
    /// <returns>A queryable.</returns>
    public static IQueryable<T> Expand<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> alias)
    {
        var nhQueryable = source as INHibernateQueryable;
        if (nhQueryable != null)
        {
            nhQueryable.QueryOptions.AddExpansion(ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(alias.Body));
        }
        return source;
    }
```

In NH4 (.Linq) there is no `INHibernateQueryable` anymore, but how can I transform this code so that it works with NHibernate 4 like it used to...?

We're using Linq to write our queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate 4 we already have Linq as a native support on the lib.

You can use `Fetch`, `FechtMany`, `ThenFetch` and `ThenFetchMany`, that will cover some possibilities with querying in relations between your entities and aggregates roots. For sample:

```
var customers = session.Query<Customer>()
                       .Fetch(x => x.City)
                       .ThenFetch(x => x.State)
                       .ToList();
```

`Fetch` and `ThenFetch` just fill a reference you can have on your entity and `FetchMany` and `ThenFetchMany` fill a collection of entities.

In NHibernate 3 we also have the `QueryOver` which is a little bit verbose (in my opinion) but it is very flexible to define your sql statements on the database.

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I decided to go for `QueryOver` because it lets me chain `Fetch` in a better way with several child elements on the root object + result transformation. Besides that writing: Extension methods for the migration process is easier, just based on type `IQueryOver<>`

Answer (score 1):

As of NH3 (I believe) you would now use `.Fetch`, `.FetchMany`, `.ThenFetch` and `.ThenFetchMany` extensions to eager load entities.

Here is an example of how I use this:

```
Order order = orderRepository.Query().Where(x => x.Id == orderId)
                        .FetchMany(x => x.OrderLines)
                        .ThenFetchMany(y => y.SubLines)
                        .ToList()
```

Comment: If those extensions looks missing for anyone, add a `using NHibernate.Linq;`. They are coming from that name space, as [`IQueryable<T>` extensions](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.cs).